# Magento Custom report module remove blank records

Tags: module, reports, collection-filtering

I have created custom report module using  below link

http://magentotutorial.org/how-to-create-magento-custom-reports/

It is working  but whenever filter by date it show some empty rows and some result rows but, I want to remove empty rows.

Comment: have any one find the solution of above issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you mean by empty rows, if it is simply one field that is empty then you have two options.

1. Validate these before saving so that they are not in the database,
2. Update the collection to filter out the empty rows in the admin section,